# accessing data members in a Linkedlist

Tags: c++, linked-list, polynomial-math

```
if (polynomial1->get(0)->compareTo(polynomial2->get(0)) == 0)
{
    polynomial1->get(0)->coefficient += polynomial2->get(0)->coefficient;
    result->insert_tail->polynomial1->get(0);
}
```

`Polynomial1` and `Polynomial2` are both Linked Lists and I am adding polynomial terms together one node at a time. In my compareTo function if both the terms in the linked lists == 0 then I want access the coefficient and add the coefficient of both terms together. My problem is accessing the coefficient. I keep getting the error message:

> class `Data` has no member named `‘coefficient’`

But my `PolynomialTerm` class inherits `Data`. Any help on accessing the coefficient?

```
class PolynomialTerm : public Data
{
    public:
    int coefficient;
    Variable *variable;

    PolynomialTerm(int coefficient, Variable *variable) :
    coefficient(coefficient), variable(variable)
    { }

    int compareTo(Data *other) const
    {
        PolynomialTerm * otherTerm = (PolynomialTerm*)other;

        return variable->variableX == otherTerm->variable->variableX &&
            variable->variableX == otherTerm->variable->variableX &&
            variable->exponentX == otherTerm->variable->exponentX &&
            variable->exponentY == otherTerm->variable->exponentY ? 0 :
            variable->exponentX > otherTerm->variable->exponentX ||
            variable->exponentY > otherTerm->variable->exponentY ? -1 : 1;
    }
```

---edit--

here is also my Data class which is located in my header file.

```
class Data {
  public:
    virtual ~Data() {}

    /**
     * Returns 0 if equal to other, -1 if < other, 1 if > other
     */
    virtual int compareTo(Data * other) const = 0;

    /**
    * Returns a string representation of the data
    */
   virtual string toString() const = 0;
};
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `class Data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're getting error here:

```
polynomial1->get(0)->coefficient
```

And (it's again my guess) this is because the `get` function is defined in base class (`Data`) and returns a pointer to `Data` (not `PolynomialTerm`). And of course `Data` doesn't have `coefficient` (only the `PolynomialTerm` does).

The compiler doesn't know that the pointer returned by `get` actually points to `PolynomialTerm` instance. Hence you get the error.

One way of fixing this would be casting the pointer type to it's actual type `PolynomialTerm*`:

```
dynamic_cast<PolynomialTerm*>(polynomial1->get(0))->coefficient
```

Comment: my get function is actually defined in my linked list class. get returns Data at the index given. each node stores data and in this case a PolynomialTerm which inherits Data.

Comment: Oh, I see. But my suggestion is still valid and should work for you. (Maybe making the linked list class to be a template would be a more elegant solution.)

Comment: I tried using your suggestion but then I get this error message: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘polynomial1-> LinkedList::get(0)’ (of type ‘class Data*’) to type ‘class PolynomialTerm’ (target is not pointer or reference)

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo here. Of course you should cast to `PolynomialTerm*` (pointer type, I've missed `*`).

Answer (score 0):

```
PolynomialTerm(int coefficient, Variable* variable):
     coefficient(coefficient), variable(variable){}
```

Your compiler may be confused by `coefficient(coefficient)`.
Change either the argument name or the member name:

```
PolynomialTerm(int coef, Variable* var):
     coefficient(coef), variable(var){}
```